# Ionic 4 SQLite "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error

Tags: angular, sqlite, angular-promise, ionic4, request-promise

I am trying to create an Ionic 4 application, and using SQLite as storage. 
I've installed the following packages:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter
npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite-porter
```

Here is my app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, 
HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy,  },
    SQLite,
    SQLitePorter,
    DatabaseService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Here is the section of my DatabaseService where the code throws an error, it fails on the `.create` and returning undefined:

```
initializeDatabase(): void {
    console.log("initializing db");
    // Define the application SQLite database
    this._SQL
      .create({
        name: this._DB_NAME,
        location: "default"
      })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        // Associate the database handler object with the _DB private property
        this._DB = db;
        console.log("db created");
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
}
```

Here is my error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at DatabaseService.push../src/app/services/database.service.ts.DatabaseService.initializeDatabase (database.service.ts:49)
    at new DatabaseService (database.service.ts:33)
    at _createClass (core.js:21263)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21225)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21189)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21897)
    at resolveDep (core.js:22268)
    at createClass (core.js:22148)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:22019)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:23245)`

Please help, I've been stuck on this for two days.

Comment: I am just testing my application on the browser using Ionic serve

Comment: try testing you application with this command

ionic cordova run browser -l

Comment: I am still getting the same error with that command `AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at DatabaseService.push../src/app/services/database.service.ts.DatabaseService.initializeDatabase (database.service.ts:49)
    at new DatabaseService (database.service.ts:33)
    ...`

Comment: are you getting the following warnings from your dev tools?

1. Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but it's not installed

2. Install the SQLite plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

if so, try testing you app on an actual device, and it will work.  Some cordova plugins are intended for use in a native mobile environment. they will NOT work in a browser-emulated Cordova environment, for example by running cordova serve

Answer (score 0):

It throws error if you are testing it in the browser because `Cordova` will run only in the mobile.You have to test the application either in a mobile or emulator

> Cordova will run only on the mobile platforms such as Android and Ios